# How can I achieve a similar look to the image inside (three axis and a solid)?

Tags: plot, geometry, axis

I would want to draw something like this, but I have no idea how, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image: Analytic Geometry Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! This produces something of this sort. The code uses an orthographic projection but you can install a perspective view, which is described in section **64 Three Point Perspective Drawing Library** of the pgfmanual v3.1.5.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={140}{10},>=stealth,
    line join=round,semithick,dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
    declare function={xmax=5;ymax=4;zmax=3;a=2;b=2;}]
 \draw[->] (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0) coordinate (O)
  -- (tpp cs:x=xmax,y=0,z=0) coordinate[label=left:$x$] (X);
 \draw[->] (O) -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=ymax,z=0) coordinate[label=above:$y$] (Y);
 \draw[->] (O) -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=zmax) coordinate[label=above right:$z$] (Z);
 \path (tpp cs:x=b,y=b,z=b-a/2) coordinate[dot,label=below:$E$](E)
 (tpp cs:x=b+a,y=b-a/2,z=b) coordinate[dot,label=left:$A$](A)
 (tpp cs:x=b+a,y=b-a/2,z=b+a) coordinate[dot,label=left:$B$](B)
 (tpp cs:x=b+a,y=b+a/2,z=b+a) coordinate[dot,label=right:$C$](C)
 (tpp cs:x=b+a,y=b+a/2,z=b) coordinate[dot,label=right:$D$](D);
 \draw (A) edge (E) -- (B) edge[dashed] (E) 
 -- (C) edge (E) -- (D) edge (E) -- (A); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for!